# ¿Que función podría usar para bloquear la pantalla del celular en Android?

Tags: android

Estoy en la creación de un prototipo que permite bloquear el celular en ciertas circunstancias, el problema es cual es el código que me permite hacer esto.

Comment: Mejora el titulo y la explicación, bloquear la pantalla, que quieres decir mantenerla encendida?

Answer (score 1):

debes usar [**lockNow**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#lockNow%28%29)

Hace que el dispositivo se bloquee inmediatamente, como si el tiempo de espera de la pantalla de bloqueo se haya cumplido.

No olvides añadir el permiso `USES_POLICY_FORCE_LOCK`.

Si tienes dudas puedes mirar, estos [**ejemplos**](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager&method=lockNow)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes acceder al gestor de Android:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
mDPM.lockNow();
```

Asegúrate de añadir los permisos convenientes en el Manifest

Comment: Si bien DPM puede usarse, esta respuesta está algo incompleta. Desde Android N es necesario llamar a los permisos en Runtime. Este ejemplo indica como aplicar la respuesta de @Elena G usando un Receiver 
para habilitar los permisos https://stackoverflow.com/a/44680730/7023800